# What's the difference between declaring and initialising an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm being asked to write a brief description on how to initialise and declare an array of different data types (string, int, double, etc) in Java. I thought initialising it would look something like this if it was of data type double:

```
double[] ArrayName = {13.5, 18.4, 19.6, 21.4};
```

OR

```
double[] ArrayName = new double[4];
ArrayName[0] = 13.5;
ArrayName[1] = 18.4;
ArrayName[2] = 19.6;
ArrayName[3] = 21.4;
```

So, if that is how you initialise an array, what would declaring an array look like?

Comment: You don't declare an array, you declare an array *reference variable*.  You may (if you wish) then *initialize* that *reference variable* with an *reference value* generated via `new` or by using the literal array notation.

Comment: I just updated my answer. @Lucas806

Answer (score 4):

Your first example will be compiled into second one.

So this code

```
double[] ArrayName = {13.5, 18.4, 19.6, 21.4};
```

contains

1. variable *declaration*: `double[] ArrayName`
2. array *instantiation*: `new double[4];` (and assigning this array object to variable `ArrayName`)
3. *initialization* of array with user's elements: `ArrayName[0] = 13.5; ArrayName[1] = 18.4; ...`.

Answer (score 2):

declaration -> `double[] x`

initialization -> `x = new double[]{.....}`

Answer (score 0):

Initializing an array:

```
double[] ArrayName = {13.5, 18.4, 19.6, 21.4};
```

Declaring an array:

```
double[] ArrayName = new double[4];
```

You did both in your example. For more information please refer to the following:

http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61b/lec/06